# MySQL 5.1 / phpMyAdmin - logging CREATE/ALTER statements

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Is it possible to log CREATE / ALTER statements issued on a MySQL server through phpMyAdmin? I heard that it could be done with a trigger, but I can't seem to find suitable code anywhere. I would like to log these statements to a table, preferably with the timestamp of when they were issued. Can someone provide me with a sample trigger that would enable me to accomplish this?

I would like to log these statements so I can easily synchronize the changes with another MySQL server.

Comment: Are you trying to synchronize all changes?  Replication may be the answer?

Comment: No. The databases contain different data, I just want to keep the structures of the tables in sync.

Comment: A short search turned up [this](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1252596&group_id=23067&atid=377410). Don't know if it is maintained (or if it is the project Jarod talks about), but it seems simple enough.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are interested to log *only* phpMyAdmin queries? If yes (and it might be the way to go because that way you are can avoid logging normal queries), take a look at Jarod's and mine answer.

Comment: Yes, it's fine if the solution only works in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Ah, well... I posted a more general answer already

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [patch](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1252596&group_id=23067&atid=377410) for phpMyAdmin which provides configurable logging with only some simple code modifications.

We did this at my work and then i tweaked it further to log into folders by day, log IP addresses and a couple other things and it works great.

Thanks @Unreason for the link, i couldn't recall where i found it.

Comment: was it http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1252596&group_id=23067&atid=377410?

Comment: @Unreason - yes that was the one.

Comment: The code looks a little complicated, but I will take a look at it.

Comment: If you run into problems expand the question, or open a new one for modifying the script.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a script that would do what you want for [mysql-proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-proxy.html) (check the link on official docs how to install the proxy).

To actually log the queries you can use something as simple as

```
function string.starts(String,Start)
    return string.sub(String,1,string.len(Start))==Start
end

function read_query( packet )
    if string.byte(packet) == proxy.COM_QUERY then
        local query = string.lower(string.sub(packet, 2))
        if string.starts(query, "alter") or string.starts(query, "create") then
            -- give your logfile a name, absolute path worked for me
            local log_file = '/var/log/mysql-proxy-ddl.log'
            local fh = io.open(log_file, "a+")
            fh:write( string.format("%s %6d -- %s \n",
                os.date('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                proxy.connection.server["thread_id"],
                query))
            fh:flush()
        end
    end
end
```

The script was adopted from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/proxy-gettingstarted.html), search for 'simple logging'.

This does not care about results - even if the query returned an error it would be logged (there is 'more customized logging' example, which is a better candidate for production logging).

Also, you might take another approach if it is applicable for you - define different users in your database and give DDL rights only to a certain user, then you could log everything for that user and you don't have to worry about details (for example - proxy recognizes the following [server commands](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-proxy-scripting-structures.html#mysql-proxy-scripting-structures-command-constants), out of which it inspects only Query)

Installing the proxy is straight forward, when you test it you can run it with

```
mysql-proxy --proxy-lua-script=/path/to/script.lua
```

It runs on port 4040 by default so test it with

```
mysql -u user -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 4040
```

(make sure you don't bypass the proxy; for example on my distro `mysql -u user -p -h localhost -P 4040` completely ignored the port and connected over socket, which left me puzzled for a few minutes)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question will fall into one of the listed in [MySQL Server logs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-logs.html)

If you just want to get the CREATE/ALTER statements, I would go with [the general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html). But you will have to parse the file manually. Be aware of the security issues this approach raises.

In your scenario, replication seems to be an overkill.

Triggers are not a valid option since they are only supported at SELECT, UPDATE and INSERT level and not ALTER/CREATE.

**Edit 1:**

The query log would be the best choice but as you mentioned on busy servers the logs would cause a considerable efficiency penalty. The only additional alternative I know of is [MySQL Proxy](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy).

Comment: The SQL server is pretty busy (over 70 queries per second), so I don't want to log every single query. And it doesn't look like it is possible to filter which queries should get saved in the general query log.

Comment: You could make the log file be a fifo which is listened to by another daemon which filters the log entries as they come in.  This would reduce the penalty as you wouldn't don't have the cost of writing everything to disk.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your best bet would be to look at the use of stored procedures and functions here to make changes to your DB. That way you could look at manually logging data.

Comment: I use phpMyAdmin to change the structure of the database, and it directly calls the ALTER/CREATE statements.